# Server architecture: websocket multicast server?

Tags: websocket, streaming, live-streaming

What would be the simplest way to build a server that receives incoming connections via a websocket, and streams the data flowing in that socket out to `n` subscribers on other websockets. Think for example of a streaming application, where one person is broadcasting to `n` consumers.

Neglecting things like authentication, what would be the simplest way to build a server that can achieve this? I'm a little confused about what would happen when a chunk of data hits the server. It would go into a buffer in memory, then how would it be distributed to the `n` consumers waiting for it?  Some sort of circular buffer? Are websockets an appropriate protocol for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one using the Ruby [Plezi framework](http://www.plezi.io) (I'm the author, so I'm biased):

```
require 'plezi'

class Client
   # Plezi recognizes websocket handlers by the presence of the
   # `on_message` callback.
   def on_message data
      true
   end
   protected
   # this will be out event.
   def publish data
      write data
   end
end

class Streamer
   def on_message data
      Client.broadcast :publish, data
   end
end

# the streamer will connect to the /streamer path
route '/streamer', Streamer

# the client will connect to the /streamer path
route '/', Client

# on irb, we start the server by exiting the `irb` terminal
exit
```

You can test it with the Ruby terminal (`irb`) - it's that simple.

I tested the connections using the [Websocket.org echo test](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) with two browser windows, one "streaming" and the other listening.

- use ws://localhost:3000/streamer for the streamer websocket connection
- use ws://localhost:3000/ for the client's connection.

#### EDIT (relating to your comment regarding the Library and architecture)

The magic happens in the IO core, which I placed in a separate Ruby gem (Ruby libraries are referred to as 'gems') called [Iodine](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine).

Iodine leverages Ruby's Object Oriented approach (in Ruby, everything is an object) to handle broadcasting.

A good entry point for digging through [that piece of the code is here](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine/blob/dedd100b3a5c75e0956481fb6e5c86112a113971/lib/iodine/http/websockets.rb#L93-L110). When you encounter the method `each`, note that it's inherited from [the core Protocol](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine/blob/dedd100b3a5c75e0956481fb6e5c86112a113971/lib/iodine/protocol.rb#L145-L154) and uses an Array derived from the [IO map](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine/blob/dedd100b3a5c75e0956481fb6e5c86112a113971/lib/iodine/io.rb#L21-L24).

Iodine's websocket implementation iterates through the array of IO handlers (the `value` half of a `key=>value` map), and if the IO handler is a Websocket it will "broadcast" the message to that IO handler by [invoking the `on_broadcst` callback](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine/blob/dedd100b3a5c75e0956481fb6e5c86112a113971/lib/iodine/http/websockets.rb#L197-L199). The callback is invoked [asynchronously](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine/blob/dedd100b3a5c75e0956481fb6e5c86112a113971/lib/iodine/core.rb#L7-L19) and it [locks the IO handler while being executed](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine/blob/dedd100b3a5c75e0956481fb6e5c86112a113971/lib/iodine/http/websockets.rb#L17-L20), to avoid conflicts.

Plezi [leverages Iodine's `broadcast` method](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi/blob/d77807ed5ecdca324ba32e646418738c6eb41e0a/lib/plezi/handlers/ws_object.rb#L243-L255) and uses the same concept so that [the `on_broadcast` callback](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi/blob/d77807ed5ecdca324ba32e646418738c6eb41e0a/lib/plezi/handlers/ws_object.rb#L72-L83) will filter out irrelevant messages.

Unicasting works a little bit differently, for performance reasons, but it's mostly similar.

I'm sorry for using a lot of shorthand in my code... pre-Ruby habits I guess. I use the `condition ? when_true : when_false` shorthand a lot and tend to squish stuff into single lines... but it should be mostly readable.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the great answer. I'm a little more interested in how to architect a solution to this problem, rather than how to implement it with a specific language. Looking forward to digging into your library to see how you did it. Thanks.

Comment: @bcattle - You're super welcome. I updated the answer with links for the relevant parts of the code, to make it easier to dig in and I attempted to give a short-hand overview of the architecture... The architecture relies heavily on the OOP model implemented by Ruby. I'm sure it can be done in C++ and maybe Rust and other OOP languages, but I'm not sure it would be as easy. Javascript prototypes and dynamic types can implement a similar architecture, but... well, I guess javascript is better than C. Single threaded is generally faster if your code never blocks on heavy tasks.