# Ready to reuse WebSocket connection server with Redis/ZeroMQ backend wanted

Tags: websocket, redis, scalability, zeromq

I need horizontally scalable WebSocket connection server for chat like system, where browser clients connected to different WebSocket servers coould exchange messages **within separate chat rooms**.

```
Clients    HaProxy  WebSocket server1   WebSocket server2    Redis/ZeroMQ
             |             |                 |                   |
client A ----=------------>o<----------------|------------------>|
             |             |                 |                   |
client B ----=-------------|---------------->o<----------------->|
             |             |                 |                   |
```

Here `client A` and `client B` are connected through `HaProxy` to two different `WebSocket servers`, which exchange messages through `Redis/ZeroMQ` backend, like in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012394/how-to-scale-node-js-websocket-redis-server) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701094/scaling-websockets-with-a-message-queue) questions.

Thinking of building that architecture I wonder if already there is an opensource analog. What such a project would you suggest to look at?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [Plezi](http://www.plezi.io) Ruby framework. I'm the author and it has automatic Redis scalability built in.

(you just setup the `ENV['PL_REDIS_URL']` with the Redis URL)

As for the architecture to achieve this, it's fairly simple... I think.

Each server instance "subscribes" to two channels: a global channel for "broadcasting" (messages sent to all users or a large "family" of users) and a unique channel for "unicasting" (messages intended for a specific user connected to the server).

Each server manages it's internal broadcasting system, so that messages are either routed to a specific user, to a family of connections or all users, as par their target audience.

You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi). The Redis integration is handled using [this code](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi/blob/86390c691e3153591ff0303636efa20283b8182f/lib/plezi/common/redis.rb#L5-L39) together with the [websocket object code](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi/blob/86390c691e3153591ff0303636efa20283b8182f/lib/plezi/handlers/ws_object.rb#L243-L264).

Web socket broadcasts are handled using both the [websocket object on_broadcast callback](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi/blob/86390c691e3153591ff0303636efa20283b8182f/lib/plezi/handlers/ws_object.rb#L72-L83). The Iodine server handles the inner broadcasting within each server instance using the [websocket implementation](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine/blob/256d8f83be2d4c5f7632b013d825b434c459f68e/lib/iodine/http/websockets.rb#L93-L110).

I already posted the inner process architecture details as [an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705911/server-architecture-websocket-multicast-server/33706596#33706596)

I think socket.io has cross server support as well.

#### **Edit** (some code)

Due to the comment, I thought I'd put in some code... if you edit your question and add more specifications about the feature you're looking for, I can edit the code here.

I'm using the term "room" since this is what you referred to, although I didn't envision Plezi as just a "chat" framework, it is a very simple use case to demonstrate it's real-time abilities.

If you're using Ruby, you can run the following in the `irb` terminal (make sure to install Plezi first):

```
require 'plezi'
class MultiRoom
    def on_open
        return close unless params[:room] && params[:name]
        @name = params[:name]
        puts "connected to room #{params[:room]}"
        # # if you use JSON to get room data,
        # # you can use room arrays like so:
        # params[:room] = params[:room].split(',') unless params[:room].is_a?(Array)
    end
    def on_message data
        to_room = params[:room]
        # # if you use JSON you can try:
        # to_room = JSON.parse(data)['room'] rescue nil
        # # we can use class `broadcast`, to broadcast also to self
        MultiRoom.broadcast :got_msg, to_room, data, @name if to_room
    end
    protected
    def got_msg room, data, from
        write ::ERB::Util.html_escape("#{from}: #{data}") if params[:room] == room
        # # OR, on JSON, with room arrays, try something like:
        # write data if params[:room].include?(room)
    end
end
class EchoConnection
    def on_message data
        write data
        MultiRoom.broadcast "myroom", "Echo?", "system" if data == /^test/i
    end
end
route '/echo', EchoConnection
route '/:name/(:room)', MultiRoom
# # add Redis auto-scaling with:
# ENV['PL_REDIS_URL'] = "redis://:password@my.host:6389/0"
exit # if running in terminal, using irb
```

You can test it out by connecting to: ws://localhost:3000/nickname/myroom

to connect to multiple "rooms" (you need to re-write the code for JSON and multi-room), try: ws://localhost:3000/nickname/myroom,your_room

test the echo by connecting to ws://localhost:3000/echo

Notice that the echo acts differently and allows you to have different websockets for different concerns - i.e., having one connection for updates and messages using JSON and another for multiple file uploading using raw binary data over websockets.

Comment: It looks like yet another broadcasting chat. Seems I need something else, or maybe I don't get how to manage separate rooms

Comment: You can use different connection routes, with different controllers, to manage "rooms". These "rooms" can communicate with each other, either sending messages to everyone in a room or targeting specific connections (or a single connection) disregarding which "room" they connected to.

Comment: My pleasure, @zuba :)